# ChargeBee - PHP create subscription breaks PHP loading the page

Tags: php, mysql, chargebee

Working on a Chargebee integration, using their suggest PHP library.

I have the include statement at the top of the page, to include the library.
And I set the environment variables with test server information copy-pasted from the control panel.

No matter what I try, when I use their sample code, my page load breaks and I get a white screen. Without this block of code, the page loads fine and all dbase calls works perfectly.

Is there more to know about the Chargebee library that I'm not catching?

```
        (in the top of the php)

                include("/app/includes/chargebee-php-master/lib/ChargeBee.php");

                ChargeBee_Environment::configure("SERVERNAME-test",
                  "test_KEYFROMCONTROLPANEL");


        (inline code in a function)

              $result = ChargeBee_Subscription::create(array(
                      "planId" => "pond_ripple", 
                      "customer" => array(
                        "email" => "john@user.com", 
                        "firstName" => "John", 
                        "lastName" => "Doe", 
                        "phone" => "+1-949-999-9999"
                      ), 
                      "billing_address" => array(
                        "firstName" => "John", 
                        "lastName" => "Doe", 
                        "line1" => "PO Box 9999", 
                        "city" => "Walnut", 
                        "state" => "CA", 
                        "zip" => "91789", 
                        "country" => "US"
                      )
                                      ));
                    $subscription = $result->subscription();
                    $customer = $result->customer();
                    $card = $result->card();
                    $invoice = $result->invoice();


                $sampleString = $customer["id"];
```

Comment: _“and I get a white screen”_ – then set up your PHP’s error_reporting and display so it’ll _show_ you what errors it encounters instead of dying silently.

Comment: Thanks. I used error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); and have been able to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your include path correct?

```
include("/app/includes/chargebee-php-master/lib/ChargeBee.php");
```

Can you crosscheck whether it starts from a base directory? ie. /app/includes/chargebee-php-master/lib/ChargeBee.php or is it relative? i.e app/includes/chargebee-php-master/lib/ChargeBee.php

If your path is right (full path), can you provide the error log to debug further? Also you need to access ChargeBee customer object as $customer->id and not as an array.